# Generate SQLite database scheme from Java code

Tags: jooq, jooq-sbt-plugin

Is there any way to generate SQLite database model from Java code using JOOQ?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate DDL statements like `CREATE TABLE ..` or `ALTER TABLE .. ADD CONSTRAINT ..` using the [`DSLContext.ddl()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#ddl-org.jooq.Table-) API, for instance:

```java
// SCHEMA is the generated schema that contains a reference to all generated tables
Queries ddl =
DSL.using(configuration)
   .ddl(SCHEMA);

for (Query query : ddl.queries()) {
    System.out.println(query);
}
```

This is documented here: 
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/ddl-statements/generating-ddl/

Comment: Can you give some example what is SCHEMA? Are these Java classes similar to JPA Entities?

Comment: @PeterPenzov: It's a generated schema reference. But hey, perhaps I misunderstood your question. Would you mind being explicit about what you'd like to do?